# Program type already present: com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService

Tags: android, android-multidex

Problem occurs only on release build or on generate signed apk, when I build debug - no such problem.

Problem arrived right after upgrade AS to version 3.1

```
Program type already present: com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

[image]
dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
    implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
    }
    implementation 'com.chauthai.swipereveallayout:swipe-reveal-layout:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.eggheadgames:Siren:1.5.0'
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.18@aar'
    implementation 'me.everything:overscroll-decor-android:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.baoyz.pullrefreshlayout:library:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:imagepicker:1.8.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.mukeshsolanki:country-picker-android:1.1.9'
    implementation 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.4'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.8.9@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.7.0.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.30.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.1.8@aar'
    implementation 'com.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4.8.8@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'
}
```

M lost to find solution to fix this, any suggestions - welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Finally was able to resolve problem by simple deleting of aidl import lib, now compilation success on both debug and release, don't know why like this, Documentation seems outdated for inAppPurchases in google, seems this class is added from somewhere automatically.

Comment: I am having the same issue, and it was fine in previous builds. 

Can you explain a bit more about what aidl files you deleted? Was it the IInAppBillingService class located at com.android.vending.billing inside src/main?

Comment: Went ahead and deleted the IInAppBillingService.aidl file, and my signed releases are working now.

I need to go check out the documentation for InAppPurchases to see if they have updated them or recommended any changes.

Comment: Looks like they still recommend adding the .aidl file, but I agree that the docs are probably just outdated.

I found the info here: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

Comment: This is actually the proper solution for it ? We can't try to exclude the module ?

Comment: This worked for me with same issue, thank you for posting, you should post it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Solution was close:
Finally was able to resolve problem by simple deleting of aidl import lib, now compilation success on both debug and release, don't know why like this, Documentation seems outdated for inAppPurchases in google, seems this class is added from somewhere automatically.

Comment: How can i do this?

Comment: Thanks, it works. The reason is you are using a billing library which already added this !!

Comment: Oh man, I have been on it all afternoon with different error messages. I have changed buildToolsVersion, compileSdkVersion, supportLibVersion, and everything else that has been suggested on the net. Finally, I deleted the aidl folder, rebuilt it, all good, added the aidl folder again and got this fault. What a joke. Their sample project has the aidl folder and shows no errors with the exact same setup. How does that work? Thanks anyway.

Comment: I have the same exact message and this solution didn't work for me

Answer (score 7):

Delete the IinAppBillingService.aidl file from the android studio and just run the app again. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 6):

- Whenever you trying to adding google play billing library with

> **implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:version-code'**

- You must **remove** IInAppBillingService.aidl file from your project.

check this path of IInAppBillingService.aidl in Project level view

> - path :- app > src > main > aidi and so on...

You just **delete** this aidi folder **or** delete IInAppBillingService.aidl and rebuild your project. An error will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Before I explain my fix, let me tell you how did I managed to create it.

I started with Ionic [In App Purchase 2](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-purchase-2) , worked perfect in development, after I've deployed with

`ionic cordova build android --prod --release`

**Fail! Doesn't work**

Ok! I thought I need to take another approach / package, so I've go to [In App Purchase](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-purchase) (version 1 if we want to call it)

After 1 try without luck in development mode, I thought , ok lets go back to Version 2, so when I've tried to deploy, 0 success!

**I tried the following things that worked for me**

1. Delete `node_modules`folder
2. Run `npm install`
3. Run `ionic cordova platform remove android && ionic cordova platform add android`

So we are clean... now the most important piece , you can't have multiple versions of in-app-purchase , so my solution was to remove the version 1.

4. Run `cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-inapppurchase`

Just to be sure if you are clean , you shouldn't be able to find any of these 2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in my case same file added two time at different location with .aidl when I search, in windows explorer source code of project then I able to find it, then I delete it, After it APK generated successfully!